# Change code page with ESC/POS on Birch printer

Tags: javascript, printing, escpos, qz-tray

I am using QZ Tray tool to send raw data to thermal printer using ESC/POS commands. This is the code I'm using and it's working as expected on most printers:

```
data = [
    "\x1b\x40",
    "\x1b\x74\x49", // ESC t 73 - switch to Windows-1251
    text + "\r\n",
    "\x1B\x74\x48", // ESC t 72 - switch to Windows-1250
    text + "\r\n",
];

let config = qz.configs.create('printer_name', { encoding: 'windows-1251' });
qz.print(config, print_data).catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

The issues I am having are with Birch CP-Q3 printer. This printer doesn't seem to execute `ESC t n` command if the n is greater than 33. Like that it doesn't recognize those code pages. Command `ESC t n` works fine if the n is less than 33.

Strangest thing is that I can switch code page to 73 for example using printer tool, but it can't be done using ESC/POS commands. Printer self test also contains those code pages.

Is there a command that I should execute before changing code page or a printer configuration that I can change so that extended code pages can be used?

Comment: The [manual](https://www.pospak.com/Attachment/DownloadFile?downloadId=279) states that the printer supports "13 international character sets".  The [zip file (191 MB)](http://www.birch.com.tw/new/?p=62) [mentions a DIP switch for 2-byte character codes](https://i.imgur.com/wMbBtRc.png), but I don't think that will help with `Cp1251`, since it's an 8-bit set.  They offer a [codepage screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/wMbBtRc.png) in the Printer.TEST.V3.1C.pdf (linked below) manual, but it's for a different model.  If you hold the feed button while powering it on, does it print a similar page?

Comment: Link to [Printer.TEST.V3.1C.pdf](https://github.com/qzind/tray/files/8399168/Printer.TEST.V3.1C.pdf), for reference. :)

Comment: Another idea is to see if you can capture the data being sent to the printer by [pausing it and opening the raw spool file](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/CapturingAWindowsSpoolFile#how-to-save-windows-spool-files-manually) when using the TEST tool, then and seeing if they're sending a different command.

Comment: ... notes from Epson's [character set command page](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32), quoting: "selected character code table is valid until `ESC @` is executed, the printer is reset, or the power is turned off. For characters in each code page, refer to Character Code Tables for [`TM printers > Single-byte Characters > Code Pages`](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/)." (not much help)  I did find a command called [`ESC R` Select an international character set](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/index.php?content_id=117) :/

Comment: Looking at the manual`80XX Program Manual(latest version).pdf` that seem to be related from the driver/manual/tool Zip introduced by @tresf, it seems that only 17 code pages are supported in the specification. It does not include CP1250(Central European), CP1251(Cyrillic). If you choose a similar alternative page, PC1250 would be PC852:Latin2(value is 18) and PC1251 would be PC866:Cyrillic#2(value is 17).

Comment: When I do printer self-test it prints out various information including all accepted code pages. This printout contains both CP1250 and CP1251.
I'll try to catch raw spool file using method proposed by tresf.

Comment: Unfortunately, Printer utility doesn't communicates directly with the printer, not using spool.

Comment: I was afraid of this, Epson does something similar when using their utility.  If the printer has a network connectivity, you may be able to capture and dump the communications with wireshark.  Another option we've done before is send every hex value from 00 to FF with the text we're trying to print, just make sure to echo the hex to the paper so you know which one worked :D :D :D

Comment: I've also submitted the question through Birch's "contact us" form on what I believe is their official website.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @tresf. Using wireshark I managed to get the following HEX dump when setting code page 73 using printer tool:
`00000000  1f 1b 1f ff 49 0a 00    ....I..`
Command I'm using is `\x1b\x74\x49`. Tired changing to `\x1f\x1b\x1f\xff\x49\x0a\x00` but no luck.

Comment: @cakan can you try to switch QZ Tray to use HEX notation (not to be confused with JavaScript's ability to escape hex, which is nearly identical), but do so with encoding set to `ISO-8859-1`?  Maybe some of the bytes are getting corrupted by the browser and/or Java.  https://qz.io/wiki/raw#hex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed Birch-POS support and they say the following:

> Please suggest customer to use command  `\x1F\x1B\x1F\xFF\x49` to set codepage to windows-1251.

Which matches the OPs wireshark comment, quoting:

> Using wireshark I managed to get the following HEX dump when setting code page 73 using printer tool:  `1f 1b 1f ff 49 ...`

Unfortunately, JavaScript (specifically, UTF-8) [does not like certain escape sequences over `x7F`](https://github.com/qzind/tray/issues/155#issue-202285236).

The working code should look like this:

```js
var text = 'Привет мир';

// Use QZ's hex mode, which can workaround JavaScript not allowing certain hex values
var data = [
   { 
    type: 'raw',
    format: 'command'
    flavor: 'hex',
    data: 'x1Fx1Bx1FxFFx49', // Instruct Birch POS: Windows-1251
    // data: 'x1Fx1Bx1FxFFx48', // Instruct Birch POS: Windows-1250
   },
   text + '\r\n'
];

// Tell Java to use a strict 8-bit encoding
var config = qz.configs.create('printer_name', { encoding: 'ISO-8859-1' });

qz.print(config, print_data).catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: It works with encoding set to Windows-1251. Thanks a lot!